# Scaling DAC voltage to smaller range for controlling gate of transistor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, dac, conversion, scaling

I need to scale a DAC voltage which is ranging from 0-5V to a voltage ranging from 3.8-4.2V to control the gate of a mosfet in its linear region. I want the 0-5V range from the DAC to linearly correspond to a voltage from 3.8-4.2V to reduce the needed resolution in regards of the DAC.

Which circuit can be used to do so?

EDIT:

I've found the following which can be helpful for other meeting similar problems.

https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/posts/handy-gadgets

Comment: You are going to have a hard time controlling MOSFETS this way. You're going to need feedback to do this properly.

Comment: I have a shunt which I'm monitoring with a MCU to determine the drain current.

Comment: well in that case, why not use the voltage dropped across your shunt as the feedback to an error amp, and use the output DAC of the MCU as the setpoint to this error amp?

Comment: The DAC will be used for controlling the current very precisely to a heating element. By using the proposed circuits in the answers I don't need a DAC with a high resolution as none of the 0-5V is unused. When I started, I connected the DAC directly to the gate and only  used it in the range between 3.8-4.2V which would mean I needed very high DAC resolution as only about 10% of it's output range was used. The reason for asking this question was to find a solution to utilize the full DAC range.

Comment: Google for span-zero (zero-span) circuit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your load is the gate of a FET, so very high resistance, it's appropriate to simply use a resistive divider here.

Three resistors and a 5 V reference, possibly available from your DAC circuit, will do.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXoIu5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've shown standard E24 values there, which give you a slightly larger range than 400 mV at your FET gate, to be safe. The exact value would be R5 = 9396 ohms.

Comment: @Nego24: Some DACs have a high-Z output or may not sink as well as source so a unity buffer may be required  on thhe DAC output before R5.

Comment: The DAC used is a TI DAC8571. I have connected the V(sense) to the Vout pin to buffer the output of the DAC.

Answer (score 2):

> *Which circuit can be used to do so?*

Most likely an op-amp circuit so, let me set the scene for you: -

- The circuit will have a gain of 0.4 volts/5 volts = 0.08
- That's because \$\frac{4.2 - 3.8}{5 - 0} = 0.08\$ = output change divided by input change
- The circuit will add an offset of 3.8 volts

Usually folk turn to an inverting summing op-amp to do this but, it gives a negative output. However, that can be turned to a positive output by using another inverting stage. Maybe this document entitled [Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf?ts=1706531718420&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) is worth a read. I think the 30 second bit is a tad optimistic but, the document has good provenance as it comes from Texas Instruments.

Or you could use a couple of resistors like this: -

[image]

R1 and R2 produce the required gain (attenuation) of 0.08 and, it's just a case of fiddling with V1 to get the correct offset on the output. Of course you can use more resistors to help you find a suitable offset voltage such as 5 volts.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to scale a DAC voltage which is ranging from 0-5V to a voltage ranging from 3.8-4.2V to control the gate of a mosfet in its linear region.

For a given MOSFET design (i.e. unique part number), different individual MOSFETs may easily have threshold voltages that vary by a factor of 2 to 1 or more. That is, one MOSFET may have a threshold voltage of 2 V, while another MOSFET of the same type has a threshold voltage of 4 V. The threshold voltage of a MOSFET is a key parameter in determining the MOSFET \$V_{GS}\$ vs \$I_D\$ characteristics.

Therefore, designing your circuit to under the assumption that you want to operate the MOSFET with the gate voltage to be between 3.8 and 4.2 V seems risky at best. Unless there is more to the story that I am unfamiliar with, this would not be a good design decision.

> I want the 0-5V range from the DAC to linearly correspond to a voltage from 3.8-4.2V to reduce the needed resolution in regards of the DAC.

Despite my recommendation against a designing for a range of 3.8 to 4.2 V, the question remains how would one implement such a linear transformation of voltages.

(TI has an appnote [Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf) which sometimes gives designs requiring negative resistors. The method I show here does not do that. The method in this answer is for circuits with positive gain less than 1, and positive level shift).

The change in input is 5 V, and the change in output is 0.4 volts. So the slope of the line relating input to output voltages is 0.4/5 = 0.08. This is a positive gain, but a gain of less than 1, i.e. an attenuation. If you have an appropriate reference voltage, **AND** the overall circuit is such that you can ignore loading effects, then you can implement a circuit that provides the specified transformation with 2 or 3 resistors. You can ignore loading effects if the output of the resistor network is connected to a high impedance load, and the input of the resistor network is connected to a low impedance source.

Since you intend to drive the gate of a MOSFET, the load will have a high enough impedance at low frequencies. If you wish it to have rapid responsiveness, loading may be an issue. Similarly, since a DAC is driving the resistor network, it may not be powerful enough to prevent loading effects especially at high frequencies. It might be prudent to use an amplifier even if the voltage transformation itself does not necessarily require it.

To determine the topology you need, you must first calculate several parameters

$$m = \frac{\Delta V_{out}}{\Delta V_{in}}$$

is the gain of the transformation

$$b = V_{out} |_{V_{in}=0}$$

is the value \$V_{out}\$ should have when \$V_{in}=0\$

The equation for the transformation is given by

$$V_{out} = mV_{in} + b$$

The input-output cross-over voltage \$V_x\$ is the voltage which if applied to the input, gives the same voltage at the output. That is, \$V_x\$ satisfies

$$V_x = mV_x + b$$

or

$$V_x = \frac{b}{1-m}$$

In your particular case, the linear transformation that you wish to implement is

$$V_{out} = 0.08V_{in} +3.8$$

So,

$$V_x = \frac{3.8}{1-0.08} = \frac{95}{23} \approx 4.13 \text{V}$$

Note that for the transformation we are trying to implement, both \$m\$ and \$b\$ are positive, and \$m\lt 1\$ This will determine the choices we have available to implement this transformation.

---

### Using \$\mathbf{V_x}\$ as a reference voltage

If \$V_x\$ is available as a reference voltage, you can implement the transformation using two resistors plus optional unity gain buffers before and/or after the resistor network to mitigate loading effects.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDe4p5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ratio of the resistors are

$$R1 : R2 = (1-m) : m$$

Using a gain m of 0.08 and \$V_x = V_{ref} = 4.13\$ we arrive at the following resistor ratios:

$$R1 : R2 = (1 - 0.08): 0.08 = 0.92 : 0.08 = 11.5 : 1$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPf5KR.png)</sup>

---

### Using a reference voltage greater than \$\mathbf{V_x}\$

If a reference voltage greater than \$V_x\$ is available, you can implement the transformation using a circuit similar to the previous one, only this time using three resistors plus optional unity gain buffers before and/or after the resistor network to mitigate loading effects.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPCu6J.png)</sup>

The ratio of the resistors are

$$R1 : R2 : R3 = \left(\left(\frac{1}{m}-1\right)\frac{V_x}{V_{ref}}\right) : 1 : \frac{V_x}{V_{ref}-V_x}$$

Using a gain m = 0.08, \$V_{ref} =\$ 5 V and \$V_x =95/23\$ V, we calculate the following resistor ratios

$$R1 : R2 : R3 = 11.5\times\frac{95}{23}\frac{1}{5}:1:\frac{\frac{95}{23}}{\frac{20}{23}}$$

$$R1 : R2 : R3 = \frac{19}{2}:1:\frac{19}{4}$$

$$R1 : R2 : R3 = 38 : 4 : 19$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQnesv.png)</sup>

---

### Using a reference voltage less than \$\mathbf{V_x}\$

If you want to use a reference voltage of, say 1.25 V or 2.5 V, which is less than the \$V_x\$ of 4.13 V, then you may use a circuit with the following topology.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8TkuN.png)</sup>

**In this case, the resistor ratios are given by**

**$$\mathbf{R1:R2 = b: mV_{ref}}$$**

**$$\mathbf{R3:R4 = 1:mk-1}$$**

**where**

**$$\mathbf{k = 1 + \frac{R1}{R2}}$$**

For a gain m of 0.08, a b value of 3.8 V, and a \$V_{ref} = \$2.5 V, resistor ratios are calculated as follows:

$$R1:R2 = 3.8:(2.5)(0.08) = 3.8:0.4 = 19:1$$

$$k = \frac{R1}{R2} +1 = 20$$

$$R3:R4 = 1: mk-1 = 5:3 $$

Here is a completed circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzkNgT.png)</sup>